# I created a Jar file with intellij but it wont run

Tags: java, javafx, executable-jar

I used the cmd command java -jar file-name.jar but it wont run.
I get an error in my cmd it states "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application"

I used these steps to create a jar: https://medium.com/@vinayprabhu19/creating-executable-javafx-application-part-2-c98cfa65801e
file but it wont run.

Comment: Which Java version is being used? (JavaFX was removed from *newer* Java versions [some years ago, Java 11] - JavaFX libraries must be added)

Comment: java 19 Oracle OpenJDK version 19

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX support has been removed from JAVA-11. You can find it in older versions. Alternatively, if you want to use a higher version of JAVA you can try the JDK of other vendors such as [AZUL OpenJDK](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk) which provides JDK with JavaFX support. Alternatively, you can use [JavaFX SDK](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) along with JDK which will provide you with JavaFX support.